# How to separate my app and web landing page on same directory?

Tags: flutter

After `flutter create myprofject` I want my app code and web landing page separated but web page and app both wants to in `lib/main.dart` file right? Or do I have to create different flutter project just for my web landing page?

On my react projects I used to separate my app and landing page like this with `firebase.json` file:

```
"hosting": [
    {
      "target": "home",
      "public": "dist/landingpage",
      "ignore": [
        "firebase.json",
        "**/.*",
        "**/node_modules/**"
      ],
      "rewrites": [
        {
          "source": "**",
          "destination": "/index.html"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a main-web.dart file. Configure all your website variables in it and then use

```
flutter run -t lib/main-web.dart
```

> -t, --target=                               The main entry-point file of the application, as run on the device.
> If the "--target" option is omitted, but a file name is provided on the
> command line, then that is used instead. (defaults to "lib/main.dart")

Also you can take a look at flutter flavor
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_flavor